# How do you add seams to a UV map without reunwrapping the entire thing?

Tags: uv

I've UV unwrapped and organized all the UV islands manually, but then I realized I want to add a new seam to one part of the mesh. However, after adding seams, it automatically UV unwraps again, ruining all my manual organization.

How can I mark seam but only UV unwrap one part of the mesh?

Comment: Do you have "live unwrap" enabled?  Check the UV menu of your UV editor viewport.

Comment: No. What does it do? I enabled it but marking seams still automatically unwraps the whole mesh

Comment: "after adding seams" does it reunwrap everything after you mark seams on the mesh or after you hit U > Unwrap to update it? Live Unwrap was mentioned as it provides behaviour of auto-unwrapping, should be disabled. It's not quite clear what happens in your case. Try also to pin those islands you want to stay on UV map.

Comment: It reunwraps everything right after I mark seams. This happens both when I have Live unwrap on and off.

Comment: It looks like you need to disable Live Unwrap in that window where you work, e.g if you have UV editor and viewport, disable Live Unwrap in viewport if you mark seams there. Also did you try to pin islands you don't want to move? (uv editor > pin islands). That could allow to work even with constant reunwrapping. Other than that if you have latest Blender, maybe report that behaviour on bug tracker

Comment: Yea I think it's a bug, currently the only solution is to separate objects and mark the seams in the separate objects so that when it auto unwraps, it only unwraps the specific part.